# USB wireless won't connect in 17.04

Tags: networking, drivers, compiling, make, ralink

I've got a problem with the driver for an RT5370 WiFi dongle which I downloaded it from the manufacturer website (www.mediatek.com/products/broadband/Wifi/rt5370; sorry, I can't post more than two links because it's my first question).
Then I followed this (superuser.com/questions/692229/install-driver-for-rt5370-on-ubuntu) and similar instructions, but they didn't work for me, I got an error running `make`. The output is about 100 lines long, the first seem to be the normal compiling output, the last ones contain errors as you can see [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25371555/).

If I try to run `make -i`, it runs longer and produces more output, resulting in [that](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25371560/).
If you have any ideas what to do, I'd be happy to try them :-)

EDIT 1:
Output of wireless-info script (thanks to chili555 for the link):

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 22 Aug 2017 20:23 CEST +0200

Booted last: 22 Aug 2017 00:00 CEST +0200

Script from: 25 Mar 2017 07:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.04
Release:    17.04
Codename:   zesty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.10.0-30-generic #34-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 31 19:38:17 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82578DM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10ef] (rev 05)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82578DM Gigabit Network Connection [103c:304b]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 148f:5370 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5370 Wireless Adapter
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04d9:a055 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04d9:a100 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
rt2800usb              28672  0
rt2x00usb              20480  1 rt2800usb
rt2800lib              94208  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              53248  3 rt2800lib,rt2800usb,rt2x00usb
mac80211              782336  3 rt2800lib,rt2x00lib,rt2x00usb
cfg80211              602112  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    16384  3 mxm_wmi,nouveau,hp_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

enp0s25: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether <MAC address>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 19  memory 0xf3100000-f3120000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 356  bytes 26544 (26.5 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 356  bytes 26544 (26.5 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx000f6008d5f1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether <MAC address>  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp0s25   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlx000f6008d5f1  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.0.53

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       872     1  0 20:22 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlx000f6008d5f1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Ralink
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        802.11 n WLAN
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rt2800usb
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.10.0-30-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         42 (The supplicant is now available)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.7/2-1.7:1.0/net/wlx000f6008d5f1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   no
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{3}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   db533785-5e2c-416a-98f0-724ec777aaaf | 802.1x-S

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s25
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        82578DM Gigabit Network Connection
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         e1000e
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.2.6-k
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               0.12-2
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/net/enp0s25
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 

SSID         BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY          ACTIVE  * 
802.1x-L     <MAC '802.1x-L' [AC2]>  Infra  9     2452 MHz  54 Mbit/s  52      ?___  WPA2 802.1X       no        
802.1x-S     <MAC '802.1x-S' [AC3]>  Infra  9     2452 MHz  54 Mbit/s  49      ?___  WPA1 WPA2 802.1X  no        
TNT-DONATOR  <MAC 'TNT-DONATOR' [AN3]>  Infra  9     2452 MHz  54 Mbit/s  42      ?___  WPA2              no        
802.1x       <MAC '802.1x' [AC1]>  Infra  3     2422 MHz  54 Mbit/s  35      ?___  WPA2 802.1X       no        

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=true

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/HUAWEI P8lite]] (600 root)
[connection] id=HUAWEI P8lite | type=wifi | permissions=user:XXXXXXX:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=HUAWEI P8lite
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/802.1x-S]] (600 root)
[connection] id=802.1x-S | type=wifi | permissions=user:XXXXXXX:;
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=802.1x-S
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Berlin (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp0s25   no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlx000f6008d5f1  14 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 14 : 2.484 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp0s25   Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)

wlx000f6008d5f1  Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC '802.1x' [AC1]>
                    Channel:3
                    Frequency:2.422 GHz (Channel 3)
                    Quality=35/70  Signal level=-75 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"802.1x"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000a98855268f
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1124ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
                       Preauthentication Supported
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC '802.1x-L' [AC2]>
                    Channel:9
                    Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                    Quality=41/70  Signal level=-69 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"802.1x-L"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000a9605b4d6e
                    Extra: Last beacon: 596ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
                       Preauthentication Supported
          Cell 03 - Address: <MAC '802.1x-S' [AC3]>
                    Channel:9
                    Frequency:2.452 GHz (Channel 9)
                    Quality=41/70  Signal level=-69 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"802.1x-S"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 6 Mb/s
                              9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000a9605c1e35
                    Extra: Last beacon: 612ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x
                       Preauthentication Supported
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : 802.1x

##### module infos ######################

[rt2800usb]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2800usb.ko
license:        GPL
firmware:       rt2870.bin
description:    Ralink RT2800 USB Wireless LAN driver.
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     9D2505A653507F57F0E0D31
depends:        rt2x00lib,rt2800lib,rt2x00usb
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption. (bool)

[rt2x00usb]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2x00usb.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 usb library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     B8A74E3557508C7071429BD
depends:        rt2x00lib,mac80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload 

[rt2800lib]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2800lib.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Ralink RT2800 library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com, Bartlomiej Zolnierkiewicz
srcversion:     D54345347C7289C8F69F4AC
depends:        mac80211,rt2x00lib
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload 

[rt2x00lib]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ralink/rt2x00/rt2x00lib.ko
license:        GPL
description:    rt2x00 library
version:        2.3.0
author:         http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
srcversion:     297D0E7AF19B14F6E138EC2
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-30-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     309C9ACED540FCAA1DE7422
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.10.0-30-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     D77C8F93375950F3BA95B16
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.10.0-30-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[rt2800usb]
nohwcrypt: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    4.930078] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 5390, rev 0502 detected
[    4.962946] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 5370 detected
[    4.993374] rt2800usb 2-1.7:1.0 wlx000f6008d5f1: renamed from wlan0
[    5.788752] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx000f6008d5f1: link is not ready
[    5.788792] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2870.bin'
[    5.857299] ieee80211 phy0: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.36
[    6.138239] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlx000f6008d5f1: link is not ready (repeated 3 times)

########## wireless info END ############
```

EDIT 2:
Now I'm able to see available WLAN networks when I click the network icon.
I can also fill in my login data, the security setting of the network is detected correctly. But when I confirm it starts loading and stops after about one minute.
It is definitely not a hardware problem, because it works on Windows 10, which I have installed on a second internal HDD. (That's also the reason some changes take some time, I have to shut down and boot to Ubuntu, check something and then go back. Sorry for that)

Comment: See that 2.6 in the title of the driver? That means that rusty old antique was written for a 2.6 series kernel version. You are running the much newer 4.10 kernel version. If your wireless is not working, installing an *older* stale driver isn't going to help. I suggest that you run and post the wireless script so that we can help you.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180

Comment: Btw, precede a command with `LANG=C` to get English output, e. g. `LANG=C make`.

Comment: What’s your question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @DavidFoerster my goal is to set up a connection to the internet via the mentioned Wifi dongle. The problem is, that I'm unable to install the driver correctly as you can see in the question. I'll add an exact description of the symptoms.

Comment: Again, **what's your question?** Also, could you please [edit] your post, when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, your build logs appear to omit the actual error messages. I mostly see messages about earlier errors. Could you please upload the entire build log(s) to a pastie service like https://paste.ubuntu.com/ and include a link to them in your question? Thanks.

Comment: @Zanna My USB wireless won't connect in Ubuntu 17.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will have much better luck if you change the encryption in the router to WPA2-AES and certainly not mixed mode TKIP.

You will also need a change to Network Manager:

```
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Add a new section as follows:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

After making these changes, reboot and let us hear the result.

Comment: this worked, thank you very much, I've been searching for hours. Thanks to @DavidFoerster as well, for giving support how to ask questions correctly